# Broken sudo-config on Azure Linux VM

Tags: linux, azure

I have a Ubuntu VM on Azure (classic virtual machines), and somehow the Azure-installed scripts have corrupted some of my sudo-config so I am unable to su on the machine.

The error I get is:

```
fran@dc-mysql:~$ sudo su -
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users: syntax error near line 125 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users near line 125
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

As far as I can tell it is not possible to connect to the booting VM and login as root, and root user login is not allowed via SSH. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Do you know the root password ?

Comment: The azure automatic VM installer disables root login via SSH, and there is no root password that I am aware of.

Comment: Disabling the root password for ssh is not the same as disabling root but I see from the azure docs that root is disabled so your options are somewhat limited. I would start here https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=azure+linux+recovery+mode

Comment: Thanks, I will try attaching the disk to another machine to fix the faulty file later today!

Answer (score 2):

Hi I know that it has been a long time, 
but recently I just got lock my sudoers file in an existing vm of azure.

There are multiples ways to solve this, the best way is using a customscript extension because Azure has root. Azure has all the power, so we can write an  script that copy the original sudoers file, or create another script that change the root password(not recommended !)

Check this for more information:
https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/automate-linux-vm-customization-tasks-using-customscript-extension/